# os.path.islink keeps returning False on Windows 10 with Python 3.8

Tags: python, windows

I'm running `os.path.islink(link_path)` on Windows 10 with Python 3.8.

The SYMLINK is obviously present on the system, but the function only returns `False`.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" are you sure it's a *symlink* and not, say, a junction point?

Comment: @Masklinn Yeah, `dir` on the symlink shows `<SYMLINK>`. Created with `mklink`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of s = os.lstat(link_path); print(f'{s.st_file_attributes:#010x} - {s.st_reparse_tag:#010x}').